# Does there exist a triple point map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, manifolds, fixed-point-theorems

It is known that for every continuous map $M:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ there are infinite double points.also by borsuk-ulam theorem this is true for each map $N:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^n, n\in \mathbb{N}$.
A question arising here concerns finding k-manifold $X$ which each map $S:X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ has a triple point.

**A:** Does there exist such $X$? if yes then how it would be figure out?

**B:** Does there exist a minimal $X$? (means the number of triple points of a map $S:X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be minimum among all $S$ and all $X$.)

**Note:** a function $f:X\to Y$ have a *double/triple point* if for a point $p\in Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ consist of **at least** 2/3 points in $X$.

Comment: This is presumably not what you want, but you could let $X$ be a 3 point space with the coarse topology. Then every continuous map to $\mathbb R$ would have to be constant.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean when you say the topology of $X$ is the same as the standard topology of $\mathbb R$. At face value that means that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Perhaps you want to insist that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: You're true I think it would be better to just mention $X$ is a metric space

Comment: Frankly, it's not clear what you mean by triple point. Is it a point in the codomain whose preimage contains exactly three points? In that case, I suspect that the quadruple point thing with the sphere doesn't actually satisfy this definition, because for example, we can just project the unit sphere in $\Bbb{R}^3$ onto its $x$ coordinate, and the fibers contain either one point or infinitely many points.

Comment: In fact you can always consider the constant map, so triple point would have to mean "at least 3 points in the preimage."

Comment: @jgon a function $f:X\to Y$ have a *double/triple point* if for a $p\in Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ consist of **at least** 2/3 points in $X$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I've edited the question and just limited to manifolds because the problem was trivial for metric spaces. It was enough to consider $X$ as union of three lines.

Comment: @jgon I've just edited the question and have limited $X$ just to manifolds, also I've added explanation about double/triple point . hope to remove "on hold".